# Python: TypeError: 'TypeVar' object is not subscriptable. How to create TypeVar with bound Generic?

Tags: python, generics, python-typing, typing, type-variables

I`m writing some ORM-like library and my model instances can exist in different forms, like this:

```py
# can have any attributes
selected_user: User[Selected] = db.select(User, ...)

# should have mandatory attributes
user_to_insert: User[ToInsert] = User.prepare_insert(...)

# should have primary key
user_to_update: User[ToUpdate] = User.prepare_update(...)
```

All of this variables are instances of same class, they all share same logic and attributes, subscription argument describes their contents. As for me, it looks, like a nice place to use `Generic` and `TypeVar`.
I have two base classes - `View` and `Model`:

```py
class View: pass

class Selected(View): pass
class ToInsert(View): pass
class ToUpdate(View): pass

ViewVar = TypeVar("ViewVar", bound=View)
class Model(Generic[ViewVar]): pass
```

It works fine to define models:

```py
class User(Model[ViewVar]):
    email: Optional[str] = ...
    name: Optional[str] = ...
```

The problem(`TypeError: 'TypeVar' object is not subscriptable`) occurs with typing of functions, processing my models:

```py
ModelVar = TypeVar("ModelVar", bound=Model)
def insert(model_to_insert: ModelVar[ToInsert]) -> ModelVar[Selected]:
    pass
def prepare_insert(model: Type[ModelVar], description: dict) -> ModelVar[ToInsert]:
    pass
```

Is there any way to use TypeVar bounded to Generic as Generic?
Why is this prohibited? Are there any alternatives?
**UPDATED**
Found a **dirty hack**:

```py
class GenericTypeVar(TypeVar, _root=True):
    def __getitem__(self, item): pass

# Changed TypeVar to GenericTypeVar
ModelVar = GenericTypeVar("ModelVar", bound=Model)
```

It`s unreadable by static analyzers, but prevents code from exception

Comment: Not yet expressible in Python's type system, sadly https://github.com/python/typing/issues/548

Comment: It is pretty old question, but I came here looking for answer. It's still not expressible with `typing` module, but possible with external dependency. Here's what I found in related discussion: [`returns`](https://returns.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/hkt.html). For the cost of single decorator (and probably negligible runtime cost) you can have generic typevars!